# Retrieve html from a modal and convert it to a string via a script

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

How do you retrieve the html within a modal's body by way of a script? Because it'd be great to convert the html into a string and then pass that content on to a controller (and ultimately on to an action method).

I thought I could do the following but just get an `undefined` message.

```
$("#sendButton").click(function () {
            alert("Send button pressed");
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("DidItWork", "Home", new { testEmail = "newtestemail@gmail.com"})',
                success: function (result) {
                    var body = $('#myModal').attr('modal-body');
                    alert("Success. It worked: " + body);
                },
```

Thoughts / suggestions on how to best turn the html element into a string so that it can be passed alongside the testEmail string in the @Url.Action? Also am I supposed to use `$('#myModal').data('modal-body')` instead of `.attr`?

**In the _layout.cshtml file there code along the lines of:**

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**And further down there is a script that has:**

```
<script>
    $("#sendButton").click(function () {
        alert("Send button pressed");
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DidItWork", "Home", new { testEmail = "newtestemail@gmail.com"})',
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Success. It worked: " + result);
            }, 
            error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                alert("Sorry, there was a problem! Error: " + errorThrown + ". Status: " + status + ". Console: " + xhr);
                console.log("Hello");
                console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
                console.log("Status: " + status);
                console.dir(xhr);
                console.log("Good-bye");
            },
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

**Which is passing the testEmail variable to the homecontroller.cs:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DidItWork(string testEmail)
{
        var dash = "dash equals nash";

        var manager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "test2 username2", Email = "testemail2@gmail.com" };
        user.Email = testEmail;
        var result = await manager.CreateAsync(user, "passwordGoesHere1!");
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await manager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account");

            return View();
        }

        //AddErrors(result);
        return View();    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the jQuery [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function to get the HTML `String` contents of a particular element.

```
$('#myModal .modal-body').html();
```

You want to get the contents of the element with class `modal-body`. In your version, you get the value of an attribute called `modal-body` on the `#myModal` element (which returns `undefined` because no such attribute exists)

Comment: Pretty much this. Your modal is part of your HTML markup, so anything you can access on the page you can access in your modal. Here's a Bootply workup of your answer: http://www.bootply.com/LtdvHvTxl0

Comment: I'm still getting "undefined". Is there anything wrong with the following code: `var body = $('#myModal.modal-body').html();
alert("Success. It worked." + body);` -- I also tried `alert("Success. It worked." + $('#myModal.modal-body').html());` but got the same thing...

Comment: You need to have a space in `'#myModal .modal-body'`. With the space it says "find an element with class 'modal-body' inside an element with id 'myModal'". Without a space it says "find an element with id 'myModal' AND class 'modal-body'". See the [MDN Article on Descendant Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification -- it works perfect now. I originally thought the space was just a typo. Also thanks for the websites/articles that you referenced.